# ASP.NET MVC Google Auth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using the MVC template with VS 2013 that allows for authentication via Google. When I click the Google link, it goes out to Google and asks for permission and I give it permission, then it comes back to the .NET sample page and asks me to make a username and all that gets stored in AspNetUsers table.

I've never done authentication before so my question is what is the data in this table and how is it used? The table has:

```
Id (GUID)
UserName
PasswordHash (NULL)
SecurityStamp (GUID)
Discriminator
```

- What is the Id, PasswordHash, and SecurityStamp fields? What does the data in them mean?
- Why does the sample have the user great a user name? Isn't the google authentication enough to identify a person?
- When I go back and click google authentication again it doesn't go back to the google site asking for permissions. Why not?
- Is the idea behind this sample, DB layout and all, safe to use for a production site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the Id, PasswordHash, and SecurityStamp fields? What does the data in them mean?

- Id is a unique identifier.
- PasswordHash is the users password stored in a way that the original password cannot (easily) be deciphered, hence "hashed".
- SecurityStamp, I believe, is used to by the hashing algorithm when generating the PasswordHash and increases the difficulty for someone to figure out the original password from the hash.

Why does the sample have the user [c]reate a user name? Isn't the google authentication enough to identify a person?

- ASP.NET identity associates the google ID you use with a "local" user account. That local user account could be associated with multiple providers like Facebook, Google, etc., or have a local password. ASP.NET Identity is handling a lot of scenarios, and it was reasonable to always require a username. What I've done when I don't want to force my users to provide a user name is generate a Guid without the dashes "-" and drop it in the user name file.
- Google is enough to verify that that person has a google account, but consider how that fact relates to your system? Your system still has to keep track of its users.

When I go back and click google authentication again it doesn't go back to the google site asking for permissions. Why not?

- At this point google has already told your app that this person owns such and such google account. So disassociating with Google is an option. I'm not sure if one user account can be associated with multiple Google accounts. I'm still fuzzy on this aspect.

Is the idea behind this sample, DB layout and all, safe to use for a production site?

- What Microsoft provides out of the box is definitely safe for production, and better than what 99% of people bake at home.

Comment: "Google is enough to verify that that person has a google account, but consider how that fact relates to your system? Your system still has to keep track of its users." - Didn't Google provide me the Id field (The guid)? Isn't that the same value by user authenticated via Google? Isn't that enough?

Comment: Also the PasswordHash value is always null. The user didn't provide any password (why would they since they logged in via Google) or is this just in the case they didn't use any 3rd party to log in?

Comment: Google does not provide the User ID. The IUserIdentity.Id string is generated within your code, for example when you use UserManager to create a new user. What google provides is an "affirmative" that you have access to a google user account.

Comment: Yep, PasswordHash will remain null until the user create a password. If they registered a "local" account they will be required to create a password. If they registered via Google they will have the option to add a password later from the Account/Manage page.

Comment: Note `var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();` in the `ExternalLoginConfirmation` action of AccountController. If `info` is null then the login provider (Google in our conversation) has not provided an affirmative that the user has an account with them.

Comment: So that Google authentication is only valid until they log out of their Google account (say on gmail)? If Google isn't providing any sort of unique ID by user, how do we associate a successful auth from Google to the actual user? There has to be a link between Google and this website's user. I'm missing something here. It can't just be the UserName because like you said you use a GUID that the user doesn't know, so they aren't entering that anywhere.

Comment: Once logged into your app a user is not logged out unless they log out or close their browser (assuming the auth cookies are tied to the current browsing session). So a user then signing out of Google after signing in to your app will not be logged out of your app.

Comment: But when they do logout and then back in, what is the association between the google auth and the account for your site? Sure a user authenticates to google, but unless you can tie that to a user on your account what was the point of doing that? What is the tie between a successful google authentication (many times between months of usage) to the user on your site? If there is no global unique user ID from google and the user isn't entering anything to login on your site, where is the link?

Comment: I believe that connection is the ProviderKey in the AspNetUserLogins table, and I believe that provider key does not authenticate that user but provides the gateway to repeatedly attempt authenticating the same Google account.

Comment: Ah OK. So for my website and for said user, that provider key will always stay the same between all google authentications between logouts? Seems like one could just use that as the user Id then as it uniquely Id's a user for ones site.

Comment: One could do that, but what if you choose to use support more providers in the future. I would stick with Guid, and avoid making an Id field contain significant data. After all, ASP.NET Identity won't use that information from the Id field anyway.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks for all your answers!

You know I used google on the demo site yesterday and I did it again today and it tried to make me a new account. This was all from VS so I wonder if I got a new port on the localhost and google treated that as a new site and so gave me a different token, which caused the demo site to try and force a register of a new client. I'll have to test that.

Comment: You're welcome. All really good questions, and you finally got me to answer some of them for myself. I would guess that your database was blown away and recreated without you realizing it, but that's just a guess.